# Why would a Mac load a different web page by default?

Tags: apache

I was working on a site the other day and hadn't set the DirectoryIndex for the public_html directory. On my Windows machine it would load index.php. However, on a Mac running Safari it was loading index.js. I didn't think that the user's browser has an effect on what Apache serves as the DirectoryIndex file. Does anyone know why this was happening?

Thanks

Comment: What does `index.js` contain?

Comment: What does safari on windows do?

Comment: Try forging the user agent.  See http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/27/how-to-change-and-spoof-safari-user-agent-string/